# Best way to remove elements from an array1 which are present in array2 Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have the following JavaScript array

```
var array1 = ['Teams' , 'Chat' , 'Zoom' , 'Slack' ] 

var array2 = [ 'Zoom' , 'Chat']
```

How to make a new array in which only those elements of array1 present which are not in array2?

New Array should look like

```
new_array = [ 'Teams' , 'Slack' ]
```

Comment: this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#filter()` method:

```
const newArray = array1.filter(e => !array2.includes(e));
```

**DEMO**

```js
const array1 = ['Teams' , 'Chat' , 'Zoom' , 'Slack' ];
const array2 = [ 'Zoom' , 'Chat'];

const newArray = array1.filter(e => !array2.includes(e));

console.log( newArray );
```

Comment: Maybe use `const` for the arrays as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will run in `O(n)` time in best, worst and average case for `n` elements in `array1` as the lookup in the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) happens in `O(1)` and will return the correct result.

Using `Array#includes()` will result in a worst case runtime of `O(n * m)` for `n` elements in `array1` and `m` elements in `array2` when all elements in `array1` and `array2` are different. And even if they are not you would on average need `m / 2` steps to find a match in `array2` using `Array#includes()`, which would still result in an average case runtime of `O(n * m)`.

```js
const array1 = ['Teams' , 'Chat' , 'Zoom' , 'Slack' ] 

const array2 = [ 'Zoom' , 'Chat']

// Create a Set for lookups in O(1); Creation will take O(n).
const array2Set = new Set(array2);
// Only return elements that are not in the Set in O(n) 
const newArray = array1.filter(item => !array2Set.has(item))

// print result
console.log(newArray);
```